# Django - Manipulating query strings (search filters)

Tags: django, query-string, django-urls

I'm looking to manipulate query strings so I can create search filters -- I was wondering what would be the best approach. I'd like to be able to add/update/remove parts. For example:

**Color**

- Blue (www.google.com/`?color=blue`)
- Red (wwww.google.com/`?color=red`)
- Green (www.google.com/`?color=green`)
- None (www.google.com/`?`)

I found a couple snippets that do this but I was looking through the docs and I saw the [QueryDict objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects). I'm not sure how that would work out in the template. What is the best and *safest* approach?